# Problem with C++ code for number theory

Tags: c++, function, recursion

```
int sum(int number, int min, int counter)
{
    int temp=0, n;
    n=number+temp;
    if ((number>=(n/2)) & (number!=min))
    {
        number --;
        temp ++;
        while (number>=(n/2))
        {
            cout << number << "+"<< temp << "\n";
            number --;
            temp ++;
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    else if (number==1)
    {
        return counter;
    }

    sum(n-1, 1,counter);
}

int main()
{
    int number,counter=1;

    cout << "Please enter the number: ";
    cin >> number ;
    cout << "\n";

    sum(number, 1, counter);
    cout << counter;

    return 0;
}
```

Does what i need it to but crashes and has a few problems with it. Just looking for some tips on how t improve it.

Also wanted to make sure I'm practicing recursion correctly. Thanks!

ADD:
The point of the program is to total the max possible ways a number can be added up.

Then the number of sequences that sum up to 6 is 11 (including 6 itself).

```
6
5+1
4+1+1
3+1+1+1
2+1+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1+1
2+2+1+1
3+2+1
4+2
2+2+2
3+3
```

I'm also trying not to have sequences that repeat, for example 2+2+1+1 and 1+1+2+2.

Comment: What's this function used for? Please provide more details.

Comment: You surely wanted a logical and here: `if ((number>=(n/2)) & (number!=min))`

Comment: @Hoàng Long: added more info check it out.

Comment: This doesn't look good. Could you please explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: @natko: I did explain, look above.

Comment: It seems you forgot to "return" at the end of sum function.

Comment: `int temp=0, n; n=number+temp;` WTH? O.o

Comment: I'm just as befuddled as natko, even after your edit.  You should add some comments explaining how your algorithm is supposed to work, particularly what each variable is supposed to represent.  And did you understand what ruslik was pointing out? There's an important difference between the `&` and `&&` operators...

Comment: @Alec: Your algorithm can't work, it prints at most pairs of numbers, so it'll never print `1+1+1`.

Comment: @Alec: in recursive calls to `sum`, and you should increment `min`, instead of decrementing `number`

Comment: @ ybungalobill: it works fine. It doesn't need to print them all it is just printing so i can double check my work. I just need to come up with a total for each number the user enters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no exit criterion. Your function will just recurse into the skies.

Comment: Took care of this now im having problems with the counter

Answer (score 2):

As I comment above in the question, your sum function doesn't return value at the end. Another problem is that you pass "counter" as a value, so it won't be changed in your main function. You should declare your function like this:

```
int sum(int number, int min, int &counter)
```

The & operator determine that "counter" is a reference variable, and can be changed by "sum" function.

And as ruslik comments, you should change operator & into &&, though it doesn't affect much here.

You can take a look at the sample code [here](http://codepad.org/jIqr9P6K).

Comment: Perfect Dumb mistakes on my part. One last problem. It returns 3+1+2 as a possibility but its already done. 3+2+1 and ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This link will help you through [here you go](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/869529-print-all-combinations-number-n-sum-positive-integers)

Modified code from Hoàng Long to achieve the desired result there is one bug it prints one extra combination but I am too lazy to solve it.

Here is the [code](http://codepad.org/jeWs3zJF)

EDIT
Corrected the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation:

```
void sum_r(int n, int m, int cnt, int* nums){
    for (;n >= m; m++)
        sum_r(n-m, nums[cnt] = m, cnt+1, nums);
    if (!n) for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++) printf("%d%c",nums[i],(i==cnt-1)?'\n':'+');
};

void sum(int n){
    int nums[100];
    return sum_r(n, 1, 0, nums);
};

int main(){
    sum(6);
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read The art of computer programming volume 4A, Knuth has clearly listed many methods in doing that, for example, one of the simplest way (without recursion) is this,

[image]